# I keep getting an error message when running my app?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation

[This](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/1647/unledhjr.png) is the error message I keep getting when I run my app in the emulator.

There's nothing in the Error Log and it doesn't really tell me where the error is coming from but I get this in the LogCat:

```
WARN/ActivityManager(51): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!

WARN/ActivityManager(51): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44e0fb68 com.gamer.network2/.FirstActivity}

WARN/InputManagerService(51): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44e98158

ERROR/gralloc(51): [unregister] handle 0x494d08 still locked (state=40000001)
```

This is my Java for the Layout that comes up when the app is started: (I would think if this is what comes up first, that would be where the problem is, but I really don't know.)

```
package com.gamer.network2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView next1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signuptext);
    next1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Screen2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
        }

    });
}
}
```

Here's my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gamer.network2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/newlogo2" 
android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".FirstActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity android:name=".Screen2"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Screen3"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Screen4"></activity>
<activity android:name=".MyOnItemSelectedListener"></activity>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

And the XML code for the layout/main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"  
android:weightSum="1"
>


<ImageView android:src="@drawable/newlogo2" 
android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:layout_marginTop="30dip" 
android:layout_height="112dp" 
android:layout_weight="0.11" 
android:layout_width="135dp"></ImageView>


<TextView 
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
android:id="@+id/textView2" 
android:text="Sign in to GameNet" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"></TextView>


<TextView 
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
android:id="@+id/textView3" 
android:text="Username:"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginLeft="70dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="15dip"></TextView>


<EditText android:id="@+id/EnterUsername" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="190dp" 
android:layout_gravity="center">
    <requestFocus></requestFocus>
</EditText>


<TextView 
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
android:id="@+id/textView4" 
android:text="Password: " 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginLeft="70dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"></TextView>


<EditText 
android:id="@+id/EnterPassword" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:inputType="textPassword" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:layout_width="190dp"></EditText>


<Button android:text="Sign in" 
android:id="@+id/button1" 
android:layout_width="121dp" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>


<TextView 
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
android:id="@+id/signuptext" 
android:text="Not a member? Sign up now!" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"></TextView>    

</LinearLayout>
```

I can post whatever other code you need to help me. =]

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the xml from layout/main?

Comment: Alright, the XML from layout main is there.

Answer (score 0):

i think onClickListener is for buttons only, not textviews

Comment: Did you import android.widget.button? Also you need to redefine the variable.